# Flask SocketIO send message from server to room

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

In my `app`, I need the `client` to join a `room` so that it may then `receive` messages from my `server`.

**Server Code**

```
@socketio.on('join', namespace='/test')
def join(message):

    join_room(message['room'])
    room = message['room']
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Entered the room ' + message['room']}, room=room)


@app.route('/scan/user/<int:user_id>/venue/<int:venue_id>', methods = ['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def scan_tablet_user_func(user_id, venue_id):

    room = 'venue_' + str(venue_id)
    socketio.emit('my response', {'data': json.dumps(my_info, ensure_ascii=False)}, room=room)
```

**Client Code**

```
$('form#join').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('join', {room: $('#join_room').val()});
            return false;
        });
```

As soon as the `webpage` loads, I enter `"venue_1"` into the `webpage form` entitled `"join"`.

The `variable` `room` on the `server` side is also set to `"venue_1"`.

The issue is that when I call the `API` `/scan/user/...`, nothing appears on my `client`. However,

```
emit('my response', {'data': 'Entered the room ' + message['room']}, room=room)
```

does appear correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you need to supply a namespace parameter to your emit in the API call, since you have defined a namespace.

`socketio.emit('my response', {'data': json.dumps(my_info, ensure_ascii=False)}, room=room, namespace='/test')`

If you don't supply the namespace you will use the default one.

Comment: Correct. When you reply to an event sent by the client, the namespace is obtained from the client event. When the server is the initiator, that context does not exist, so you have to provide the namespace.